# How to know the status of call on android programatically

Tags: android

I have an app that has to perform certain actions after phone call is ended. 
like in my application after every call i should save the call time, duration and write it to text file for further processing. Main problem here is how do I know that call is just ended.

I have checked Telephony manager like

```
 TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING
 TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
```

But I am still unable to achieve this task. Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). And [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) is a nice tutorial on how to catch changes in the phone state.